Unable to run spring boot project after importing from github
I have cloned a repository from github. But i realise that under the boot dashboard, there are no available projects for me to run. Please help
I tried right clicking the project and go to run configuration. Then i tried to run the application. There was an error that says: An internal error occurred during: "Launching 314 - Application".
Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.core.IJavaProject.getResolvedClasspath(boolean)" because "project" is null
Screenshot of project

You just opened the project you need to import the gradle project into eclipse. Currently Eclipse thinks it is just a random collection of files.

Import -> Gradle -> Existing Gradle Project, then select your project and finish the import wizard. That way, the IDE will recognize the project as a Java and a Spring project, enable all the Java and Spring tooling, and the project will show up in the boot dashboard (as long as it is a Spring Boot project).
